# How do I select the item with the highest value using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine you got a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    string key;
    int value;
}
```

How would you select the Foo with the highest value from an `IEnumeralbe<Foo>`?

A basic problem is to keep the number of iterations low (i.e. at 1), but that affects readability. After all, the best I could find was something along the lines of this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> list;
Foo max = list.Aggregate ((l, r) => l.value > r.value ? l : r);
```

Can you think of a more better way?

Edit: `list.OrderByDescending(l => l.value).First();` was my preferred option, but it is not O(n).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can grab the [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) LINQ extension method from Jon Skeet's [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project. Then it's just:

```
Foo max = list.MaxBy(f => f.value);
```

Comment: or, list.Where(w => w.value == list.Max( m => m.value))

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
list.OrderByDescending(l => l.value).First();
```

or

```
list.OrderBy(l => l.value).Last();
```

Comment: This is what I was using earlier, but I think it is not O(n).

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo foo = list.Max();
```

But you have to implement IComparable interface for Foo type;

Comment: Nice idea, but I can't change Foo.