# Create a list from another grouped list. (Rate by date)

Tags: c#, .net

I got a list of a Collection that has many attributes. Specifically 3 of them are: ID1, ID2 ( both IDS are keys from my table wich ID1 will always be the same in that case), Quantity and Date.

Some facts:

- I'll get a list by selecting all the ID1 numbers.
- I need to check how many ID2 duplicates records I have ( It's possible to return more than 2 records) with ID1 and ID2.
- If I have more than 1 record with the same ID1 and ID2, I will need to check from those duplicated records wich one have (if they have) the same quantity. Inside this records, I'll need to get the lastest ( using the DATE variable) record wich repeated more times.

Let me try to sample that:
Sample 1:

- Record 1: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/09/2011
- Record 2: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/10/2011
- Record 3: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 10, Date = 11/10/2011
- Record 4: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 13, Date = 11/10/2011

I'll need to add the element (ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/10/2011) to te result list. Repeated 2 times and its newer than the record with date  11/09/2011

Sample 2:

- Record 1: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/01/2011
- Record 2: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/02/2011
- Record 3: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/05/2011
- Record 4: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/07/2011

I'll need to add the element (Record 4: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/07/2011). Even with the same range of 2 records of quantity 100 and 120, The lastest one is from  11/07/2011.

Sample 3:

- Record 1: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/01/2011
- Record 2: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/02/2011
- Record 3: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/05/2011
- Record 4: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/07/2011
- Record 5: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/08/2011

I'll need to add the element (Record 3: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/05/2011). Even with a record from 11/08,  the 120 quantity repeated 3 times, so Ill get the lastest record with this quantity.

Sample 4:

- Record 1: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/01/2011
- Record 2: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 3, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/02/2011
- Record 3: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 4, Quanity = 120, Date = 11/05/2011
- Record 4: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 5, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/07/2011
- Record 5: ID1 = 1, ID2 = 5, Quanity = 100, Date = 11/08/2011

I'll need to add the record 1, record 2, record 3 and record 5 ( the 5th record duplicated and I need to get the lastest one);

I just spent a bunch of lines of code that doesn't have good performance so I would like to ask you if you guys know a better solution for that.

I will leave a code that Im trying to develop and let's see if this make any sense for you guys.

I got the following entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
  pulic int? ID1 {get; set;}
  pulic int? ID2 {get; set;}
  pulic int? Quantity {get; set;}
  public DateTime? Date {get; set;} 
}
```

My controller has a method that uses this entity as a list and recieve from database a buch os registers:

```
List<MyEntity> list = new List<MyEntity>();

//The Method "getObjects" recieves the parameters ID1, ID2. Since the 2nd parameter is null.
//It will return a list with all the ID2 registers since they have the same ID1 as the one I used.
list.AddRange(getObjects(ID1,null);
```

I definitelly have no clue on how to proceed with my requirements. I don't know if its better first of all separate ony the records wich just have only one record and then filter the other records or do everything together.

There are some users that is going to check some equipment inside trucks. Each guy into each truck generate an id (ID1) with the date of that. This ID refers to the hole conference that this specific user is doing. Each equipment (ID2, another table) got an exclusive ID with its specific quantity (Quantity). As it depends on human, I need to consider that this conference may have any mistake. Thats why I need to consider the quantity that repeated most of the time. If I have a 100 quantity two times after the last 120 quantity that repeated four times, I would consider the last register from the ID1 and ID2 who got 120 quatity

Comment: Pls post the code you had written

Comment: I think you'll need to be a little clearer on what you're doing. It looks like an SELECT N+1 issue but I could be wrong because I don't know if "Ill get the most recent record of the repeated ones." means a SELECT query, a for loop , or a Linq Query, or something completely different

Comment: Can you add the source code?  We're shooting in the dark without it to see how we could help your code be more efficient.

Comment: @ConradFrix I have a Date ( DateTime type that's impossible to duplicate) variable wich I can get the lastest one since I have all the duplicated ( elements that have the same ID1, ID2 and Quantity) records

Comment: Guys, I just added some information, could you help me ? Im still trying to develop this.. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd break it down into 2 simpler steps.

```
// for each combination of ID1 and ID2
// return the latest item from the 
// most frequently-occuring quantity
IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetLatestMaxByID(IEnumerable<MyEntity> list) {
    foreach (var group in list.GroupBy(x => new { x.ID1, x.ID2 }))
        yield return GetSingleItemForIDs(group);
}

// return the latest item from the 
// most frequently-occuring quantity
MyEntity GetSingleItemForIDs(IEnumerable<MyEntity> list) {
    return list.GroupBy(x => x.Quantity)
               .MaxBy(g => g.Count())
               .MaxBy(x => x.Date);
}

// use MaxBy from the morelinq (http://code.google.com/p/morelinq) 
// or use a simplified one here
// Get the maximum item based on a key
public static T MaxBy<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, U> f) {
    return seq.Aggregate((a, b) => Comparer<U>.Default.Compare(f(a), f(b)) < 0 ? b : a);
}
```

Comment: Its looks great ! Thanks for the help. Let me ask: If the date came from another entity that contains the ID1. (MyEntity with ID1, ID2 and Quantity) and antoher entity with (ID1, Date). The code is going to change a lot? Thanks again !

Comment: @Dan-SP: I'm not sure how you can get the date from that format. For example, If you have `(ID1, ID2, Quantity) = [(1,20, 5), (1, 21, 10)]`, and you have `(ID1, Date) = [(1, '1/1/2011')]`, how do you know which record that `1/1/2011` applies to?

Comment: Its kind an order ! So, the OrderID is ID1, DATE = Date of the order, ID2 = ID of each product of the order.. So I can consider that the  ID2 were ordered in ORDER X and the DATE Y. The date will be applied to all ID2 of ORDER ID1.

Comment: @Dan-SP: In that case, it wouldn't change the code much, but it would be actually simpler. In your examples, you have different dates for each order, but if you know the date is always the same for an order, you don't even need to check it in `GetSingleItemForIDs` and only need to worry about the Quantity.

Comment: I just edited the main post because my explanation got pretty long. Check that. The last Paragraph.

Comment: This is still killing me.. heheh.. Just tryed to improve your sample but its getting the highest quantity and the highest quantity isn't necessary the most relevant record for me. I need the quantity that is most commom..

Comment: sorry, I now understand what you want. check my edit. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004204/how-do-i-select-the-item-with-the-highest-value-using-linq for a discussion about `MaxBy`

Comment: Mate, thank you so much for the help. I'll test the script and if I have any issue Ill be back with the error. Anyway, this code database from google is suberb ! loved it.. hehe.

Comment: Jimmy, spent some hours testing any case that came from my mind and everything worked nicelly. This case for sure is the most difficultv that I have ever passed. Thanks so much for your help